Properties of a locally constant sheaf with fixed stalk $G$.
I'm trying to prove the claim below using an exercise from Hartshorne. Take the exercise as a fact.
1. Hartshorne II Exercise 1.22: Glueing Sheaves.
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{U_i\}$ an open cover of X. Let $\mathcal F_i$ be a sheaf on each $U_i$ and for each $i, j$ there's an isomorphism $\varphi_{ij} : \mathcal F_i |_{U_{ij}} \to \mathcal F_j |_{U_{ij}}$ where $U_{ij} = U_i \cap U_j$ such that $\varphi_{ii} = $ id and for each $i, j, k$ $\varphi_{ik} = \varphi_{jk} \varphi_{ij}$ on $U_{ijk}$.
Then there exists a unique sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$ along with isomorphisms $\psi : \mathcal F |_{U_i} \to \mathcal F_i$ such that for each $i, j$, $\psi_j = \varphi_{ij} \psi_i$ on $U_{ij}$.
2. Claim.
Take $X = [0,1]$, let $F$ be a locally constant sheaf with stalks $G$ for some fixed abelian group $G$. Show there is an isomorphism of sheaves $\varphi: F \xrightarrow{\thicksim} G_X$.
3. Thoughts and Questions

Please provide a detailed proof that uses glueing sheaves.
How do we use the fact that $\mathcal F$ always has stalks $G$? I want this to mean that whenever $\mathcal F$ is constant on some $V \subset X$, $\mathcal F|_V = G_V$ -- but fairly sure this isn't true.
If you want to give an alternative proof using $\pi(X)$ and representations, assume I have no knowledge about this equivalence and justify it from the ground up -- but I'd still like to see the approach requested in 1.
This post comes close to answering my question, but see 3 above. I don't understand how the transition function comes into play, it's not clear to me that such a natural transformation exists by definition, and the diagrams appear to be over modules rather than sections.


What makes you think 2. is not true? If $\mathcal F|_V\cong A_V$ and $x\in V$, then $G\cong F_x\cong A$.

If $\mathcal F$ is locally constant, there exists an open cover $X=\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ such that $\mathcal F|_{U_i}$ is constant, i.e., the sheaf of locally constant maps $V\to A$ for each open $V\subset U_i$ and some set/abelian group/... $A_i$. The condition that all the stalks give the same set/abelian group/... $G$ implies that $A_i\cong G$ for all $i$ (s.t. $U_i\not=\emptyset$, which can be assumed w.l.o.g.). However, there might be a twist, i.e., the isomorphisms $\eta_i\colon \mathcal F|_{U_i}\to G_{U_i}$ will, in general, not be compatible. Therefore, there has to be something special about $X=[0,1]$ going on that enables us to alter them so that they do agree on the intersections, thus enabling us to glue them to a global isomorphism $\eta\colon \mathcal F\to G_X$. (Recall that a collection of sheaf morphisms $\eta_i\colon \mathcal F|_{U_i}\to \mathcal G|_{U_i}$ glue to a global one if and only if they agree on the pair wise intersections: $\eta_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}=\eta_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}\colon \mathcal F|_{U_i\cap U_j}\to \mathcal G|_{U_i\cap U_j}$—this is the much simpler morphism-version of the sheaf-glueing proposition cited in the OP.)
On the closed interval $X=[0,1]$, any open cover may be refined to one with the following properties:

$I=\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ is finite,
inductively denoting $V_0:=U_0$ and $V_k:=V_{k-1}\cup U_k$, we have that $V_{k-1}\cap U_k$ is connected (and non-empty) for each $1\leq k\leq n$.

(Take a refinement by connected opens, then find a finite sub-cover; it may be supposed that no open of the resulting cover completely contains any other. Finally, order them by ascending suprema, say. Concretely, it can be arranged that $V_k=[0,b_k)$ where $0<b_0<b_1<\dots < b_n=1$ and $U_k=(a_k,b_k)$ for $0<k<n$ and $U_n=(a_n,1]$ with $a_k<b_{k-1}$.)
Let $\nu_0=\eta_0\colon F|_{V_0}\to G_{V_0}$ be our base-line isomorphism. Reasoning inductively, suppose we have extended $\nu_0$ to an isomorphism $\nu_{k-1}\colon F|_{V_{k-1}}\to G_{V_{k-1}}$. We have to show that it is possible to extend it even further to $\nu_{k}\colon F|_{V_{k}}\to G_{V_{k}}$. By assumption, $W= U_k\cap V_{k-1}\not=\emptyset$ is connected. Thus, there are two possibly distinct isomorphisms $(\eta_k)_W,(\nu_{k-1})_W\colon \mathcal F(W)\to G$. Let $\psi= (\nu_{k-1})_W\circ(\eta_k)_W^{-1}\in\mathop{Aut}(G)$, let $\psi_{U_k}$ denote the induced (constant) automorphism $G_{U_k}\to G_{U_k}$ and define $\eta'_k\colon=\psi_{U_k}\circ\eta_k\colon \mathcal F|_{U_k}\to G_{U_k}$. This is still an isomorphism, but by construction $\eta'_k|_{W}=\nu_{k-1}|_W$. Therefore, $\nu_{k-1}$ and $\eta'_k$ glue to give an isomorphism $\nu_k\colon \mathcal F|_{V_k}\to G_{V_k}$, as claimed.
